# JavaScript not able to find angularjs generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my angularjs generated ng-repeat to load images in a slider. Then i use a javascript to fetch the div under imageHolder. 
The java script is shown below. The problem is that the java script doesn't find the angularjs generated divs but if i hardcode a div there, then the javascript finds it. 
Any solution ?

```
 <div id="imageHolder" style="width:527px" >
                  <div alt="{{l.link}}" style="background-color:white; background-image:url({{l.link}}) ;
                  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;
                  background-position:center; width:70px;height:85px;
                  display:inline-block;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; margin:8px;
                  float-inherit"
                  ng-repeat="l in imageLinks "  
                  ></div>


                  <div alt="img/nex1.jpeg" style="background-color:white; background-image:url(img/nex1.jpeg) ;background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;background-position:center; width:70px;height:85px;display:inline-block;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; margin:8px;float-inherit">
                  </div>


                </div>
```

JavaScript to get the div:

```
$('#imageHolder div').hover(function(){
console.log('inside hover function');});
```

'inside hover function' gets printed for the hardcoded div but not for the angularjs generated divs.

Comment: Let me know, if my ans is doesnt work too.

Comment: Now, it have to be work)

Comment: Why aren't you using [ng-mouseenter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter) ?

Comment: Are you sure you want the hover even on `div` inside `#imageHolder` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use angular directives to attach behaviour to elements. For hover, angular has [ng-mouseenter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter).

Define the function to call on your controller:

```
$scope.onHover = function(l) {
    console.log('inside hover function', l.link);
};
```

Then attach this to each `div`:

```
<div alt="{{l.link}}" style="background-color:white; 
      background-image:url({{l.link}}) ;
      background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;
      background-position:center; width:70px;height:85px;
      display:inline-block;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; margin:8px;
      float-inherit"
      ng-repeat="l in imageLinks"
      ng-mouseenter="onHover(l)">
</div>
```

Comment: :) Mostly you don't need jquery. I'd recommend not tagging it for angular questions

Answer (score 0):

As the divs are generated later, .hover() does not identify those,
Use .on() jquery event as

```
$(document).on( "hover","#imageHolder div", function() {
  console.log('inside hover function');
});
```

Comment: And the problem is that all these work for the hardcoded div but not for the angularjs generated divs

Comment: @Legendary : it is anyway the same, use of .on() event, Abhinav do you see any jquery errors in console which may break the script? Also try including this code in document ready

Comment: Now, u just repeat mine)

Comment: Legendary, i tried ur updated answer also. Still doesn't work. And these codes are working fine for the hardcoded div, they just dont work for the angularjs divs.  Chaitanya Gadkari, there aren't any erros in console. And what do u mean by document ready ? I'm including this in a angularjs partial! All works for the hardcoded div, doesn't work for angularjs divs

Comment: Chaitanya Gadkari, tried your updated answer, still doesn't work for angularjs divs.   Legendary, what more do u want to see ? i sent the html divs and jquery funcation.

Comment: @AbhinavPathak : i think you should try jonnyynnoj's answer. it looks more appropriate. also pederOverland's answer should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those divs are available in the Dom when you're making the bind?

I think that may be the problem.

Comment: how do i check if they are available in DOM ? When i do inspect element i can see those divs but not in view source, obviously because this is an angularjs app and partials html wont be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#imageHolder div').hover(function(){
console.log('inside hover function');});
```

You should do

```
$('#imageHolder').on('hover', 'div', function(){
console.log('inside hover function');});
```

This is because when you do the 'bind' call, the divs arent in existence. The 'on' method catches all divs because it attaches the handler to the parent element.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Exactly same situation, works for hardcoded div but not for angularjs divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Directive and the property div : [AngularJS Directive docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the link function is called after the html is compiled, so your ng-repeat will be applied

//index.html

```
<div id="imageHolder" style="width:527px" >
    <div alt="{{l.link}}" style="background-color:white; 
          background-image:url({{l.link}}) ;
          background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;
          background-position:center; width:70px;height:85px;
          display:inline-block;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; margin:8px;
          float-inherit"
          ng-repeat="l in imageLinks " my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

//app.js

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //controller code
}])
.directive('myDirective', function() {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).on('hover', function(){
        console.log('inside hover function');
    });
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
});
```

Comment: shouldn't  'my-directive' in the html code and 'myDirective' in the directive be exactly same literals?

Comment: Nop, AngularJS will camelCase the attribute `my-directive` to find an existing directive